# Is there a way where a website (remote) would talk to a set local machine when the ip of the local machine is configured in that website?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, windows-services, communication

Hi i would like to know if there is any way where the remote machine would talk to a set local machine when a request is made to a remote machine from any other computer

Reason: I have a website (Apache/MySQL/PHP) with many restrictions and i want to be able to make simple services where they would talk and on my Machine some way may be a windows service that might listen to a web call from the remote machine once the windows service listens to the call it would compute what ever it needs to computer and send the result to the request call and that website receives the object and then available to the world.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Ah...what kind of restrictions? And if you really need, VPS's (virtual private server) are pretty cheap. I personally use [Linode](https://www.linode.com/), but there are several other good ones out there as well. Or find a better web host.

If you still insist on going this route, here are a couple of things you'll need to be aware of.

1. Your IP address may change, so you'll need a dynamic DNS host, and make sure the code on the web server can handle not being able to access the machine and that the dynamic DNS host is updated regularly.
2. You need to port-forward a specific port to your home machine. Unless your home machine has a public IP.